# What if Draupadi incident had not happened, whether Duryodhana was a great emperor?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, history, kali-yuga

Ramayana and Mahabharatha both happened for the reason of a female. What if that situation not araised, What could have been happened?

Is this the game plan of Lord Sri Krishna and such things are applicable for Kaliyuga as well?

Here there is no such Draupadi nor Sita, Kaliyuga consists of mostly perverts and all are used to it in one or the other way. No meaning left in relationships, bondings.

Apart from answering to the above question, What can happen to Kaliyuga for its end? Is it global warming and not with any interference of female?